# Align text right inside bootstrap card footer

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

In the bootstrap card footer, I am trying to show the status "Lost" towards the right side. The problem is if I am giving some margin-left to fix it in chrome, then its not looking same in Microsoft edge browser. How would I manage it so it works fine on all browsers.
Below is my what I have tried in fiddle.

```
    <div  class="card tile-card">
   <div class="card-header p-3 pt-2">
      <div class="icon icon-lg icon-shape bg-gradient-dark shadow-dark text-center border-radius-xl mt-n4 position-absolute">
         <i class="fa fa-icon fa-solid fa-dollar-sign opacity-10"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="text-end pt-1">
         <p class="text-sm mb-0 tile-title-p">ABC</p>
         <p class="text-xs mb-0 tile-subtitle-p">PQR</p>
         <p class="text-xs mb-0 tile-subtitle-p" style="font-weight:bold;font-style:italic">123</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card-footer p-3">
      <p class="tile-subtitle-p tile-subtitle-footer mb-0">Updated On: <b>10/27/2023 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
      <span style="color: red; font-style: normal; margin-left:26px;">Lost</span></b></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

[My fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/TechBrania/0dc25rzL/11/)

Comment: You should add the BS4 stylesheet to your fiddle (you can use a CDN link from the getbootstrap website, and add it as an external resource in your fiddle), otherwise this doesn't make that much sense as an example in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe Added the BS4 CDN link.

Comment: _"How would I manage it so it works fine on all browsers."_ - I would change the structure of that footer content first of all. There shouldn't be all those non-breaking spaces in there to begin with - _spacing_ between elements, is CSS' purview. I'd make that "Lost" text be a separate child of the `.card-footer`, and then make that footer itself a flexbox element as well. Then you can use the usual alignment mechanisms of flexbox.

Comment: otherwise you should add `float:right;` to the span's style (not bootstrap oriented and dirty opposed to the flex strategy)

Comment: Could you please edit my fiddle to show how to make that "Lost" text a separate child of the .card-footer, and then make that footer itself a flexbox element. Sorry I am not so good in CSS

Comment: @DiegoD - Yeah let me try that. Thanks.

Comment: I add a comment because I didn't know this fact and found out only now.. but you may still stick with bootstrap4 just styling the span with the class `float-right`and adding the class `clearfix` to the container

Comment: @DiegoD - The issue is fixed by using float-right on the span. Thank u so much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to align the **"Lost"** status to the right side of the card footer in a consistent way across different browsers, you can use the `ml-auto` class by Bootstrap. This class sets the left margin of an element to auto, which causes it to be pushed to the right side of its container.

use the `ml-auto` to align the **"Lost"** status to the right side of the card footer.

**Code:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card-footer p-3 d-flex justify-content-between">
  <p class="tile-subtitle-p tile-subtitle-footer mb-0">Updated On: <b>10/27/2023</b></p>
  <p class="tile-subtitle-p tile-subtitle-footer mb-0 ml-auto">
    <span style="color: red; font-style: normal;"><b>Lost</b></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

and added the `d-flex` and `justify-content-between` to the card footer to make it a flex container and align its children to the left and right sides. use the `ml-auto` to the **"Lost"** status element to push it to the right side of the container.

[JSFiddle: Result](https://jsfiddle.net/livealvi/kyvhg5fe/1/)

Comment: Yup this also works perfectly. Thanks @Diego D

Comment: @Obraine you are welcome.. but this answer doesn't belong to me.. I just edited this original answer to add the code suggested by its author inside a live snippet and make it easier to see. Credits to him

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed by using float-right on the span. I removed the margin-left property from the span.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div  class="card tile-card">
   <div class="card-header p-3 pt-2">
      <div class="icon icon-lg icon-shape bg-gradient-dark shadow-dark text-center border-radius-xl mt-n4 position-absolute">
         <i class="fa fa-icon fa-solid fa-dollar-sign opacity-10"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="text-end pt-1">
         <p class="text-sm mb-0 tile-title-p">ABC</p>
         <p class="text-xs mb-0 tile-subtitle-p">PQR</p>
         <p class="text-xs mb-0 tile-subtitle-p" style="font-weight:bold;font-style:italic">123</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card-footer p-3">
      <p class="tile-subtitle-p tile-subtitle-footer mb-0">Updated On: <b>10/27/2023 
      <span style="color: red; font-style: normal; float:right;">Lost</span></b></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Below is the updated working fiddle.
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TechBrania/0dc25rzL/15/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `bootstrap` library for your page then you can do it with multiple way. the better way is to to use `d-flex` class which sets our data in row wise and also add `justify-content-between` element class to apply space between the child class. Add this two classes with `card-footer` element to apply flexbox container.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card-footer p-3 d-flex justify-content-between">
  <p class="tile-subtitle-p tile-subtitle-footer mb-0">Updated On: <b>10/27/2023</b></p>
  <p class="tile-subtitle-p tile-subtitle-footer mb-0">
    <span style="color: red; font-style: normal;"><b>Lost</b></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

**Note:** I am using latest version of bootstrap `5.3.2` for this code